# Website loading issue in all browsers on DSL Connection

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, networking, dns, server

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and i am using a DSL Connection.From last few days i am having problem in loading some websites like ubuntuforums, hackerrank, mdn etc. I have tried alsmost all solutions available on internet. I am only having this problem on dsl connection. On wifi everything works fine.

1) I have changed default dns to google public dns.

2) This is the outcome of my `traceroute ubuntuforums.org`

```
SinScary "at" avenger:~:$traceroute ubuntuforums.org
traceroute to ubuntuforums.org (91.189.94.12), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  100.65.128.1 (100.65.128.1)  0.943 ms  0.916 ms  0.578 ms
 2  * * *
 3  172.31.210.158 (172.31.210.158)  1.657 ms  1.649 ms  1.634 ms
 4  172.31.10.73 (172.31.10.73)  1.950 ms  1.901 ms  1.881 ms
 5  10.0.248.2 (10.0.248.2)  2.134 ms  2.126 ms  2.225 ms
 6  ws86-230-252-122.rcil.gov.in (122.252.230.86)  1.834 ms  1.372 ms  1.891 ms
 7  ws85-230-252-122.rcil.gov.in (122.252.230.85)  1.716 ms  1.830 ms  1.900 ms
 8  172.31.210.42 (172.31.210.42)  2.193 ms  2.184 ms  2.231 ms
 9  172.31.10.66 (172.31.10.66)  39.689 ms  39.668 ms  39.665 ms
10  172.31.10.198 (172.31.10.198)  2.109 ms  2.163 ms  2.093 ms
11  aes-static-113.195.22.125.airtel.in (125.22.195.113)  1.898 ms  1.863 ms  2.436 ms
12  182.79.245.141 (182.79.245.141)  214.911 ms 182.79.222.109 (182.79.222.109)  220.000 ms *
13  * * *
14  ae-126-3512.edge5.london1.Level3.net (4.69.166.45)  151.005 ms ae-123-3509.edge5.London1.Level3.net (4.69.166.33)  149.374 ms  141.512 ms
15  SOURCE-MANA.edge5.London1.Level3.net (212.187.138.82)  195.375 ms  159.963 ms  160.023 ms
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

3) I have disabled ipv6 as suggested in this [Answer by Mitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149669/webpages-not-loading-in-12-04)

4) It successfully pinging from ubuntuforums.org, hackerrank.com

5) Appended `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolve.conf`

6) Reinstalled Chrome

7) Also tried the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

8) Tried disabling dns masq

9) This is the output of `route -n`

```
SinScary "at" avenger:~:$route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         100.65.128.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
100.65.128.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
SinScary "at" avenger:~:$
```

10) This is the output of `cat /etc/hosts`

```
SinScary "at" avenger:~:$cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   avenger
127.0.0.2   sinscary.com    sinscary

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
SinScary "at" avenger:~:$
```

This is the error i am getting while loading websites

[ERR Timed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhbtx.png)

Any Help with this.

Comment: Run ```mtr``` and check if you have packet loss. You can try to lower the MTU f.e. to 1400 as well.

Comment: tried that too, but in vain, even reinstalled ubuntu but after some time again started getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure you have no packet loss? Do you use a proxy?

Comment: No i don't use any proxy and also this problem is not consistent. Its like for 1 hour its working fine and again it will stop loading some website and again and again.

Comment: Check for packet loss when you actually have the problem, if it happens during prime time your ISP has bandwidth problems.